# Output of Popen's communicate has non-empty stderr although there is no error

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to understand the behavior of `stdout_data` and `stderr_data` of python's `subprocess` module `(Popen.communicate())`. When output of a command is slightly large, stderr is non-empty. stdout has expected output. Output is only few KB and not MBs in size in below example. [Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) has this Note

```
Note: The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.
```

I'm assuming it is referring to GBs of output and unable to fit in RAM. It should not apply to my case.

minimum working example of the problem.

```
import subprocess


def test():
    # cmd = ["curl", "www.google.com"]  # This has non-empty content in stderr  
    cmd = ["echo", "Hello World"] # This has empty stderr
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell=False)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    if stderr:
        print("Failed")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

When `cmd = ["curl", "www.google.com"]` content of `stderr` is amount of data downloaded (bytes received, transferred, average speed etc.)

I'm trying to understand the internals of why this is happening.

Comment: What are you asking about specifically? Your example works as expected for me (prints `Failed` for the `curl` and nothing for `echo).

Comment: @dogman288 Sorry if question was not clear. Why is `stderr` populated for `curl` command while it is not for `echo`? Both commands ran successfully.

Comment: Some commands choose to use `stderr` to report information, even if the program runs successfully (i.e. the return code is 0). Imagine you redirected `stdout` of curl, but still wanted to see progress information: `curl -L google.com > output.html`. If `stdout` included both the status and the HTML, they would be a garbled mess. `curl --silent` suppresses the status information, so in that case `stderr` would be empty.

Comment: That's clear now. The `--silent` flag is useful information.